# Java Jackson how to use the default serializer for an object in a custom serializer

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, serialization, jackson

I have custom superclass called Resource, and I would like that every time a instance of Resource (or instances of subclasses) is serialized two extra fields are added to the JSON. I am using Spring Boot (if that matters) and Jackson. My idea was to define a custom serializer for Jackson to use, however my current implementation has some problems.

```
@JsonComponent
public class CustomJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Resource> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Resource resource, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,
                      SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {

        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("type", "special");

        jsonGenerator.writeFieldName("data");
        jsonGenerator.writeObject(resource);

        jsonGenerator.writeFieldName("links");
        jsonGenerator.writeObject(resource.getId());

        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Unfortuantly the call `writeObject(resource)` just re-enters my CustomJsonSerializer entering a recursive loop.

An important note, Resources can be nested and thus the it is not good enough to simple serialize the resource with a default serializer.

What I am looking for is something along the lines of a `writeAllFields(resource)` method. It is of course possible to implement one myself using reflection but then I ignore all of the Jackson annotation which is also something I would like to avoid.

EDIT:

The Resource class is a super type and the intended behavior is for all subclasses of Resource to go through this serializer(this is already the case).

```
public class Resource {
    String id;

    protected Resource() {}

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}

public class Item extends Resource {
    // Fields and methods, nothing special
}
```

EDIT 2:
In case it matters, this is how I register my serializer with Spring Boot:

```
    @Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    SimpleModule m = new SimpleModule();
    m.addSerializer(Resource.class, new CustomJsonSerializer());
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder().modules(m);
    converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(builder.build()));
}
```

Comment: Can you post the source definition of the Resource class?

Comment: @EricGreen I updated the question with the information you requested.

Comment: In your serializer, you call a #links method, but I don't see it in the definition of your Resource class.

Comment: My bad, I simplified the code a little bit to make it easier to understand.

Comment: So, are you wanting to serialize concrete subclasses of Resource such that {"links": <object_id>, "data": {"field1": "value1", "field2": "value2", ...} where "data" consists of all the additional fields for the concrete subclass?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: See my solution in the answer below. Should have completely nailed it if I'm understanding you correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The title of your post declares that you would like to access the default serializer from within your custom serializer as the person in the following post is attempting to do:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jackson-user/cFQhuyw8vpw

If you scroll to the bottom, the guy says:

> The only way to access what would otherwise be created/used as the 
>   standard serializer is to register `BeanSerializerModifier`, and 
>   override handling of `modifySerializer`.

You can also have a look at this tutorial on advanced serialization features in Jackson where the guy is doing something similar to what you're trying to do:

http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-field-custom-criteria

But, by looking at your code I infer that you are attempting to achieve polymorphic serialization of subtypes of class Resource.

If so, below is a simple solution that is hopefully precisely what you're looking for:

---

Resource.java

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;

@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ResourceFoo.class, name = "foo"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ResourceBar.class, name = "bar")
})
public abstract class Resource {

    private String id;

    @JsonProperty("links")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

---

ResourceFoo.java

```
public class ResourceFoo extends Resource {

    private String fieldA;

    private String fieldB;

    public String getFieldA() {
        return fieldA;
    }

    public void setFieldA(String fieldA) {
        this.fieldA = fieldA;
    }

    public String getFieldB() {
        return fieldB;
    }

    public void setFieldB(String fieldB) {
        this.fieldB = fieldB;
    }
}
```

---

ResourceBar.java

```
public class ResourceBar extends Resource {

    private int fieldX;

    private int fieldY;

    public int getFieldX() {
        return fieldX;
    }

    public void setFieldX(int fieldX) {
        this.fieldX = fieldX;
    }

    public int getFieldY() {
        return fieldY;
    }

    public void setFieldY(int fieldY) {
        this.fieldY = fieldY;
    }
}
```

---

SerializerDemo.java

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class SerializerDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enableDefaultTyping();

        ResourceFoo foo = new ResourceFoo();
        foo.setId("abc");
        foo.setFieldA("Apples");
        foo.setFieldB("Oranges");

        String fooJson = mapper
                .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                .writeValueAsString(foo);

        System.out.println(fooJson);

        ResourceBar bar = new ResourceBar();
        bar.setId("xyz");
        bar.setFieldX(12);
        bar.setFieldY(238);

        String barJson = mapper
                .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                .writeValueAsString(bar);

        System.out.println(barJson);
    }
}
```

---

SerializerDemo output:

```
{
  "type" : "foo",
  "fieldA" : "Apples",
  "fieldB" : "Oranges",
  "links" : "abc"
}
{
  "type" : "bar",
  "fieldX" : 12,
  "fieldY" : 238,
  "links" : "xyz"
}
```

For more info, Eugen Paraschiv has published a nice little article on this as well:

http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    @JsonComponent
    public static class CustomJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Resource> {
        private void serializeFields(Resource bean, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider)
                throws IOException {
            JavaType javaType = provider.constructType(Resource.class);
            BeanDescription beanDesc = provider.getConfig().introspect(javaType);
            JsonSerializer<Object> serializer = BeanSerializerFactory.instance.findBeanSerializer(provider,
                    javaType,
                    beanDesc);
            serializer.unwrappingSerializer(null).serialize(bean, gen, provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void serialize(Resource resource, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,
                              SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
            jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
            jsonGenerator.writeStringField("type", "special");

            jsonGenerator.writeFieldName("data");
            jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
            serializeFields(resource, jsonGenerator, serializerProvider);
            jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();

            jsonGenerator.writeFieldName("links");
            jsonGenerator.writeObject(resource.links());

            jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This does not work, found a similar answer like this one on another question and that didn't work either so it might have something to do with how I pass my objectmapper to spring. So my question now is, what is the best way to provide Spring boot with my custom serializer?

Comment: This is the error spring gives me when I try this:   Could not write JSON: [no message for java.lang.NullPointerException]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: [no message for java.lang.NullPointerException]

Comment: @LasseJacobs If you provide the full exception stacktrace, I might be able to help you (drop it in e.g. pastebin.com). A more general comment: it is fine to try to simplify your code before asking your question, but make sure to actually do it in your project, and not just when you ask your question. Try to see if my suggestion works, if you use Jackson directly to serialize your Resource ( jdoodle.com/a/zcC ). If that works try to see if you actually have a problem with Spring and the serializer: add a breakpoint or a log-line to the serialize-method and figure out if it is getting called.

Comment: Where is the `.unwrappingSerializer(null)` for? For me, it works fine if I omit it, but it gives an error if I add it,.